# Github pat token set in Renviron, but still asked for credentials on git pull

Tags: r, git, rstudio

I put my github pat token into ~/.renviron

`GITHUB_PAT=xxxxxxx`

I check in R console on Rstudio that it is indeed there:

```
> Sys.getenv()[grepl('GIT', names(Sys.getenv()))]
GIT_ASKPASS            rpostback-askpass
GITHUB_PAT             ghp_xxxxx
```

However, Rstudio still asks for credentials (username + password) every DAY I git push/pull.

After I put in credentials the first time, I do not need to for the rest of the day. But the next I will have to put them in again.

I can push/pull in terminal without entering credentials

This is on my ubuntu EC2 + rstudio. Locally I can get renviron to work with my github pat.

The remote is set with HTTPS

I put in my github credentials into ~/.renviron

EDIT:

```
> usethis::git_sitrep()
Git config (global)
• Name: 'Victor Yuan'
• Email: 'victor.2wy@gmail.com'
• Global (user-level) gitignore file: <unset>
• Vaccinated: FALSE
ℹ See `?git_vaccinate` to learn more
ℹ Defaulting to 'https' Git protocol
• Default Git protocol: 'https'
• Default initial branch name: <unset>
GitHub
• Default GitHub host: 'https://github.com'
ℹ '/home/ubuntu/.Renviron' defines environment variable(s):
  - GITHUB_PAT
  This can prevent your PAT from being retrieved from the Git credential store.
ℹ If you are troubleshooting PAT problems, the root cause may be an old, invalid PAT defined in '/home/ubuntu/.Renviron'.
• Call `edit_r_environ()` to edit that file.
ℹ For most use cases, it is better to NOT define the PAT in `.Renviron`.
  Instead, call `gitcreds::gitcreds_set()` to put the PAT into the Git credential store.
• Personal access token for 'https://github.com': '<discovered>'
• GitHub user: 'wvictor14'
• Token scopes: 'gist, repo, user, workflow'
```

Comment: What does `usethis::git_sitrep()` return?

Comment: updated in comment